# The JSON parse not working and the attribute does not appear

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm still learning the JSON, so when I try to do this the name did not appear.

index.php :

```
$myObj->name = "John";
$myObj->age = 30;
$myObj->city = "New York";
$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
echo $myJSON;
header("Content-Type: text/html");
```

index.html :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("input").blur(function() {
                var data = "pName=" + $(this).val();
                //alert($(this).val());
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "index.php",
                    data: data,
                    success: function (respond) {
                        var JQuery = JSON.parse(respond);
                        $("#result").html('');
                        $("#result").append(JQuery.name);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC44o.png): [image]

[image]

Comment: You should use $myObj = new stdClass(); before add values in object

Comment: You should also echo the data _after_ you've set the header. All headers must be set before any output at all. You should also post what the result is. What does it actually echo? What does your ajax request get? You need to show us proper examples of the issue and expected results.

Comment: Also, your JS looks strange. No matter what input field just lost it's focus, you use the value of that input (no matter which input it is) and use it as name? Is there only one `<input />` field on that page?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes it only one input, because I tried some idea came to my mind.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson what I'm trying to do is when the user enters a name I create a PHP object and then show the name, the code here is like a sample.

Comment: I get what you're trying to do, but you say that it doesn't work so you need to _show_ us how it doesn't work. In your success callback in the ajax request, do a `console.log(respond)` and see what it actually contains (add the output to your question). We can't debug your code for you.

Comment: is it okay now? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Please add `console.log(respond)` in the top of your success-function callback in your javascript and check in your console what that outputs. You're most likely getting some error/warning message in PHP, which makes the output invalid json (causing the error you're currently getting when trying to parse it as json)

Comment: Btw, where is the PHP code located? Is there more code/html on that page? If yes, then you should make sure the PHP code is in the top (before any other output) and then end that PHP snippet with `exit;` (after the echo, which you should move to after the header()) to stop the rest of the page to render (which would also mess up the json)

Comment: there is no code after the echo. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Then do as I also suggested, but the PHP code in the top of your index.php file with an exit after it. Or better yet, create a new file that only has the PHP code and call that file in your ajax instead. The output shows that you return HTML _and_ Json, which won't work. Looking at the output, you do output data after the echo, or the json would be last in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

Try this code. you forgot to declare the object. `$myObj = new stdClass();`

```
<?php
$myObj = new stdClass();

$myObj->name = "John";
$myObj->age = 30;
$myObj->city = "New York";
$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
header("Content-Type: text/html");
echo $myJSON;
?>
```

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, Updated. Thanks.

Comment: @Razan, can you share me the folder stucture?

Comment: @Razan, Seems your `url: "index.php",` path is wrong. its return html script.

Comment: I add it to the question .@Vel

Comment: show me the output like this https://imgur.com/KYUzTAW

Answer (score 0):

change

```
header("Content-Type: text/html");
```

to

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, it finally works <3

```
$myObj = new stdClass();
$myObj->name = "John";
$myObj->age = 30;
$myObj->city = "New York";
$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
header("Content-Type: text/html");
echo $myJSON;
exit();
```